# Hey, Poincaré! Do vectors have type?

Tags: linear-algebra

As I ask more questions trying to sort out how the jargon of Linear Algebra fits together, I'm starting to think of both column and row vectors as *sometimes* having a type, if you'll allow me to borrow jargon from Computer Science.

Here's what I mean:

Vectors have an order. That is--where their components are written has a meaning, it isn't arbitrary (by that I mean that if $a \neq b$ then $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}b & a\end{bmatrix}$), and that order-based meaning sometimes has a type in the Computer Science meaning of the word *"type"*.

Sometimes. Maybe.

Let there be a vector $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$ in a space whose basis is $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$, where $\hat{i} = \begin{bmatrix}d \\ e \\ f\end{bmatrix}$, $\hat{j} = \begin{bmatrix}g \\ h \\ l\end{bmatrix}$, and $\hat{k} = \begin{bmatrix}p \\ q \\ r\end{bmatrix}$, and $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$, $h$, $l$, $p$, $q$, and $r$ are all scalars.

So, what do I mean by *"type"* in this context? I mean that the $a$ in $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$ can't always be meaningfully combined with the $b$ in $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$ because $a = a * d + a * g + a * p$ and $b = b * e + b * h + b * q$ *even though they both come from fields made of real numbers*, seemingly the same field<sup>1</sup>.

Which is wild to me. Or at least it would be if it were true? ...Is it? :/

If it is true, it would be in this sense that $a$ and $b$ have different types: they can't be meaningfully combined despite both coming from fields of real numbers. Maybe we could say the *"type"* of $a$ is the set $\{d, g, p \}$ (and I'm using a set here because I'm trying to say order *doesn't* matter when defining *"type"*), and the scare-quotes *"type"* of $b$ is set $\{ e, h, q \}$.

Meanwhile, we have the dot-product of two matrices:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g & j & m & p\\
h & k & n & q\\
i & l & o & r\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u & v \\
w & x & y & z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

where the entire freaking alphabet is scalars<sup>2</sup>.

I put $a$ through $r$ in the places they're in intentionally. I'm imagining a computer running a compiler that ingests the expression above using a grammar that produces this token stream, "New vector, $a$, $b$, $c$, end vector. New vector, $d$, $e$, $f$, end vector, ... " and so on, scalars ingested in alphabetical order, up to $r$.

You can see how in my thought experiment, the first matrix on the left is meant to be understood as a matrix composed of two row vectors, and the next matrix is meant to be understood as being composed of four column vectors *from the same vector space*. In other words, in my thought experiment
$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
d & e & f \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
g \\
h \\
i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
j \\
k \\
l \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
m \\
n \\
o \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
, and
$
\begin{bmatrix}
p \\
q \\
r \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
all have the same *"type"*.

From the dot-product above, this is true:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
g \\
h \\
i \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Looks like the type of $s$ got messed up, doesn't it?<sup>3</sup>

It's almost as if the definition of how to perform the dot product imposes the view that the left operand *should* be thought of as a tuple of row vectors (where the counting and order implied by *tuple* runs vertically down the side of the matrix), and the right operand *should* be thought of as a tuple of of column vectors.

And yet in Linear Algebra we are *always* free to think of all the matrices in the equality above as being composed of both column and row vectors--aren't we?

My understanding is we are. And yet, not only does the dot product seem to imply we're not, there's the ideas of row space and row vectors. We say that the number of scalars in a column vector must have some sort of one-to-one correspondence with the number of scalars that make up all the basis vectors of the space the column vector came from. But we also say that no such constraint applies to row vectors. In fact, we say a subset of the scalars that compose a row vector *should* have a one-to-one correspondence with the components that make up the vectors that span the row space, and some of the complement of that set is just kind of extra.

So, in Linear Algebra we are *always* free to think of all the matrices in the equality above as being composed of both column and row vectors, we are to think of whether a vector is standing or laying down as cosmetic--but whether a vector is standing or laying down changes how we understand the space it defines.

Also seemingly contradictorily, there's the fact that a vector and its transpose are not logically equivalent: you can't swap a vector with its transpose in an expression and be guaranteed the meaning of the expression hasn't changed<sup>4</sup>.

Given all of this, how can we say that the difference between a column and a row vector is mere cosmetics? Is this what Henri Poincaré meant when he said, "Mathematics is the art of giving the same name to different things"?

Am I right to think of vectors as having type? I know the answer is no, but--why? What breaks when you throw my definition of *"type"* into the mix--particularly when I'm basically saying two vectors have the same type when they come from the same vector space? How is Linear Algebra *not* broken *without* type?

If writing a vector standing up versus laying down is merely cosmetic, why do so many people lose their minds when I use $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$ interchangeably in a sentence?

$\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}$

<sup>1</sup> Though I suppose the $^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the abstraction that shows up when people are defining vector spaces, implies that all the real number fields are being treated as though they aren't logically equivalent. That is, maybe it implies that the first real number line in an $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space can't be linearly combined with the second real number line in that $\mathbb{R}^n$. And *I think* that's indeed the case: $n$ is the number of basis vectors defining $\mathbb{R}^n$.

<sup>2</sup> [Sup](https://media.istockphoto.com/id/616000622/photo/little-boy-standing-against-wall-showing-his-muscles.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=X9n8UuPu3zdPR0daeyxx43Zjnsn3KQr6eV8Bh2pYq48=).

<sup>3</sup> I guess that's why they call it <s>the blues</s> [a transformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaM7OCEm3G0).

<sup>4</sup> In fact, I think the meaning of the expression will always change, right?

Comment: You should really consult a textbook about linear algebra. A vector is an object that has a length and a direction. Two vectors can be added and stretched. That's it. From that point on, we can have additional functions like an inner product of vectors, an angle between them, or other features. They require additional assumptions and are not automatically present. Hence you must not distinguish vectors by the type of operation, rather you must distinguish the operations! Here is a good article about the geometry of vevtor spaces: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5935.pdf

Comment: Expanding on the excellent comment above, I'd say two key concepts would help answer basically all your questions: the actual definition of a vector (as an element of a vector space over a field $k$), and how one chooses a basis (and further, how one writes vectors as linear combinations of basis vectors, and how one changes a basis). Personally I'd recommend "Linear Algebra Done Right" for the former, and Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra" for the latter.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a few key points:

1. Take note of how [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaM7OCEm3G0) says to think of the dot product's left operand as a transformation function and the right operand as a tuple of column vectors, and that the transformation function *takes a tuple of column vectors from one vector space and gives you their expression in the language of some other vector space*. Which vector space? The one from which the column vectors of the right operand were taken.
2. Build up the dot product equality expression one vector at a time. Or if you want to avoid some work, toggle row and column vectors in and out of the equality.

When you toggle the number of column vectors in the left operand, you change the dimension of the vector space into which your translation function translates:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g & j & m & p\\
h & k & n & q\\
i & l & o & r\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u & v \\
w & x & y & z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
translates four, three-dimensional vectors into four, two-dimensional vectors.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g & j & m & p\\
h & k & n & q\\
i & l & o & r\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u & v \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
translates four, three-dimensional vectors into four, one-dimensional vectors. So, toggling the dimension of the vector space from which the left operand's column vectors are pulled also changes the dimension of the vector space into which the transformation function transforms vectors.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g & j & m \\
h & k & n \\
i & l & o \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u \\
w & x & y \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
translates three, three-dimensional vectors into three, two-dimensional vectors.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
d & e
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g & j & m & p\\
h & k & n & q\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t & u & v \\
w & x & y & z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
translates four, two-dimensional vectors into four, two-dimensional vectors. (Maybe the basis of the vector space for the left operand are different from the basis of the vector space of the right operand; maybe they're not.)

So, the height of the right operand fixes the dimension of the transformation's input vectors, the width of the right operand fixes the number of output vectors, and the height of the left operand fixes the dimension of the output space.

3. The height of a column vector necessarily fixes the dimension of the vector space from which its drawn, the width of row vectors in any context *does not* necessarily fix the dimension of the row space from which its drawn (the dimension of a row space is always less than or equal to the width of a row vector taken from the row space). So, no--the difference between row and column vectors is not merely cosmetic.

Comment: "the width of row vectors in any context does not necessarily fix the dimension of the row space from which its drawn" - yes it does. You may be doing something that only requires a subspace of that row space - for instance, looking at the image of some non-surjective transformation, but that does not limit the dimension of the row space itself, any more than examining the kernel of the transformation limits the dimension of the column space. Both exist in a bigger context, and pretending that one of those contexts exists but the other does not is disingenuous.